# Unable to run hello world application as shown in O'Reilly - Introduction to Kotlin Programming

Tags: kotlin

I am trying to duplicate the hello world program from the O'Reilly video - Introduction to Kotlin Programming (The Structure of a Kotlin Application).

This is the program (Main.kt):

```
package com.hadihariri.kotlincourse
fun main(args: Array<String>)
{
    println("Hello World!")
}
```

Compiled with "kotlinc Main.kt"

The video shows this way to run it:

```
java -cp .:<path to kotlin runtime>/kotlin-runtime.jar com.hadihariri.kotlincourse.MainKt
```

which for me is:

```
java -cp .:~/.sdkman/candidates/kotlin/current/lib/kotlin-runtime.jar com.hadihariri.kotlincourse.MainKt
```

The runtime does exist at that location:

```
ls -al ~/.sdkman/candidates/kotlin/current/lib/kotlin-runtime.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 879182 Jun  8 18:23 /home/user/.sdkman/candidates/kotlin/current/lib/kotlin-runtime.jar
```

However, I get the same error you get without specifying the runtime in the class path:

```
java -cp .:~/.sdkman/candidates/kotlin/current/lib/kotlin-runtime.jar com.hadihariri.kotlincourse.MainKt
Exception in thread "main" 
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: kotlin/jvm/internal/Intrinsics
    at com.hadihariri.kotlincourse.MainKt.main(Main.kt)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: kotlin.jvm.internal.Intrinsics
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 1 more
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue was that apparently, the Java classpath processor does not expand the ~ (tilde) character. When I replaced that with the actual directory path, the program ran. Using $HOME in place of ~ also worked. And finally, it will work if the ~ (tilde) character is at the front of the classpath. Apparently the shell only expands it if it is in the front:

```
java -cp ~/.sdkman/candidates/kotlin/current/lib/kotlin-runtime.jar:. com.hadihariri.kotlincourse.MainKt
```

Comment: Yes, you figure out for yourself :)